# Regular expression for finding words containing the root and excluding some words containing the same root on Python3

Tags: python, regex, python-re, regexp-replace, regexp-like

Advice on how to write

- took the root "aero", but
- with the exception of "aerosol", "aerob"?

  (aero) -- Finds the group of a character in a given order.

  [^aerosol]|[^aerob] - Excludes words containing combinations of letters "aerosol",  "aerob"?

Comment: Negative lookahead? https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: What about `"aerobatics"` (as opposed to `"aerob"`)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a negative lookahead, which is a way of making sure that certain characters aren't found after a match -- in your case, you want `aero` but not `aero-sol` or `aero-b` (dash just used for affect). Here would be an example:

- [`^aero(?!(?:sol|b))\w*$`](https://regex101.com/r/ysTdrQ/1)

[image]

Comment: You don't need the non-capture group. `^aero(?!sol|b)\w*$` is sufficient (as I'm sure you know). IMO it would be clearer to write, "...but not aerosol or aerob...".